# Assign a value to a certain position in a vector of a vector (2D)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Ok, im starting c++ and i want to assign a value to a specific position in a vector of a vector. I have done it with an array of array (2D) but now would like to do it with vectors.

```
   int main() {
        int newLine = 10;
        int newColumm = 10;
        const string WALL = "\u2588";
        cout << endl;
        string grille[10][10];
        for (int j = 0; j < newColumm + 1; j++) {
            int i = 0;
            grille[i][j] = WALL;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < newColumm + 1; j++) {
            int i = newLine + 1;
            grille[i][j] = WALL;
        }
```

I would like to do the same thing with vectors.
I Have :

```
  int main() {
    int newLine = 10;
    int newColumm = 10;
    const string WALL = "\u2588";
    cout << endl;
//    string grille[10][10];
    vector<vector<string>> grille;


    for (int j = 0; j < newColumm + 1; j++) {
        int i = 0;
        grille.at(i).at(j) = WALL;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < newColumm + 1; j++) {
        int i = newLine + 1;
        grille.at(i).at(j) = WALL;
    }
```

It's obviously not working for the moment.
(Sorry for my bad language, english is my second language...)

Comment: The `at()` method accesses an existing element in the vector. `vector<vector<string>> grille;` creates a completely empty vector. There's nothing existing there. That's why `at()` throws an exception. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how vectors work and read it. It should explain how to ***resize*** the vector to some size. Here, you have to: 1) resize the major dimension of the vector to N elements. 2) Resize each one of those elements, each individual `std::vector<std::string>` to a vector of 10 strings. P.S. const string WALL = "\u2588"; is wrong.

Comment: const string WALL = "\u2588"; is ok, its a special caracter of std library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector has no size.  You are getting a `std::range_error` exception when you access the vector out-of-bounds.  Since you are not handling exceptions, your program crashes.

The naive fix for this is to simply pre-allocate your vector to the dimensions you expect:

```
vector<vector<string>> grille(10, std::vector<string>(10));
```

Note that your for-loops will naturally overshoot anyway and you'll still get an exception, since they are actually looping to 10 *inclusive*.  Remember that if you have 10 elements, then the valid indices are 0 to 9 inclusive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to size my vector!

Comment: But, do the grille.at(i).at(j) = WALL is a good method to assign the value??

Comment: If it works for you, it's fine.  Personally, I only use `.at` if I'm not certain of the dimensions and am also handling exceptions, or want a guaranteed crash with a useful stack if I access out-of-bounds.  For me to tell you whether it's "good" or not in this instance is kinda pointless, since the example you provided is contrived or simplified and also has undefined behavior.  There are lots of ways to initialize elements of a vector.  Choose one that you are comfortable with and move on.